# node.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token !=

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing an API using stormpath and node.js.
However, when I attempt to run the create_user script in node it gives me an error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token !="

this is my tools.js file:

```js
var stormpath = require('stormpath')
var util = require ('util');
var appHref = 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/KzUPEioLybUfu2YwUjb8o';
var client;
var app;

// Find the user's home directory (works on both Windows and *nix):
var home = process.env[(process.platform === 'win32' ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME')];
var apiKeyFilePath = home + '/.stormpath/apiKey.properties';

module.exports = {
  createClient: function (apiKeyFilePath) {
    this.createClient ={
      if (apiKeyFilePath != 'undefined') {
        stormpath.loadApiKey(apiKeyFilePath, function apiKeyFileLoaded(err, apiKey) {
          client = new stormpath.Client({ apiKey: apiKey });
          console.log('apiKey found... Client Created');
        });
      }

      else {
        var apiKey = new stormpath.ApiKey(
          process.env['STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID'],
          process.env['STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET']
        );
        var client = new stormpath.Client({ apiKey: apiKey });
        console.log('apiKey created... Client Created');
      }
    }
  },
  createUser: function () {
    this.createUser={
      this.createClient;

      client.getDirectory(usersHref, callback);
      var account = {
        username: 'example',
        email: 'example@gmail.com',
        password: 'Changeme!'
      };
      RMFapp.createAccount(account, function(err, createdAccount) {
      console.log(createdAccount);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

This is my create_user.js file:

```js
var stormpath = require('stormpath')
var util = require ('util');
var tools = require('./tools');
var appHref = 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/application/KzUPEioLybUfu2YwUjb8o';
var usersHref = 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/directories/13tj6f50q7jJ7WvDu6SxHa';
var client;
var app;

console.log(tools.createUser);
```

when I run node create_user.js this is the response:

```sh
if (apiKeyFilePath != 'undefined') {


SyntaxError: Unexpected token !=
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/spiffysaxman/projects/RMFapp/RMF/www/assets/api/v1/create_user.js:3:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Please help!

I have had people suggest I simply remove this.createClient ={...) and this.createUser ={...), however when I remove those I simply get this in return: "[Function]"

Comment: It's the line above: `this.createClient ={` I don't think you mean this line here at all (I think you mean just the createClient function definition above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several problems with the code

1) Starting with createClient

```
createClient: function (apiKeyFilePath) {
this.createClient ={
  if (apiKeyFilePath != 'undefined') {
    stormpath.loadApiKey(apiKeyFilePath, function apiKeyFileLoaded(err, apiKey) {
      client = new stormpath.Client({ apiKey: apiKey });
      console.log('apiKey found... Client Created');
    });
  }
```

In here you seem to be redeclaring this.createClient inside createClient.
I would change it to look like below

```
module.exports = {
createClient : function(){
  if (apiKeyFilePath != 'undefined') {
    stormpath.loadApiKey(apiKeyFilePath, function apiKeyFileLoaded(err, apiKey) {
      client = new stormpath.Client({ apiKey: apiKey });
      console.log('apiKey found... Client Created');
    });
  }

  else {
    var apiKey = new stormpath.ApiKey(
      process.env['STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID'],
      process.env['STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET']
    );
    var client = new stormpath.Client({ apiKey: apiKey });
    console.log('apiKey created... Client Created');
  }
}
,

createUser: function () {
  this.createClient;
  client.getDirectory(usersHref, callback);
  var account = {
    username: 'example',
    email: 'example@gmail.com',
    password: 'Changeme!'
  };
  RMFapp.createAccount(account, function(err, createdAccount) {
  console.log(createdAccount);
  });


}

};
```

You have a similar error in the createUser function so I changed that too. I don't know if that will solve all your problems given that I do not have strompath to run on my machine, but those are the ones I could find. Hope that helps

Comment: After making those changes it simply returns "[Function]"

Comment: tools.createUser should have parenthesis behind it since it is a function call in create_user.js

Answer (score 0):

In `tools.js`:

```
createClient: function (apiKeyFilePath) {
  this.createClient ={  // this line is the issue, remove it and the } that closes it
    if (apiKeyFilePath != 'undefined') {
```

Also, once that's fixed, you will get another error due to:

```
createUser: function () {
  this.createUser={  // this line
    this.createClient; // and this line

    client.getDirectory(usersHref, callback);
```

That will need to be corrected in the same manner.

Comment: After making those changes it simply returns "[Function]"